# Why does adding EmailAddressAttribute to a property causes EditorFor to fail?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I have a string property on my model object called `EmailAddress`. I'm using `Html.EditorFor` to render input fields for all string properties on this page, and a custom editor template which works fine. However, the minute I add the `EmailAddressAttribute` to this property, EditorFor appears to no longer detect the property as a string type, or at least, it refuses to use the editor template I have for strings.

This works:

```
[DisplayName("EmailAddress")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Must be <= 100 characters.")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

// and then in my view...
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
```

This does not:

```
[DisplayName("EmailAddress")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Must be <= 100 characters.")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Invalid email address.")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

// and then in my view...
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.EmailAddress)
```

In the second example, the default string editor template is used instead of my own. Other properties on the same model render using the correct editor template.

Am I missing something obvious or does this seem like a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[EmailAddress]` attribute sets the property's DataType to `EmailAddress`, which causes `EditorFor()` to look for an `EmailAddress` template.

Comment: Wonderfully inconspicuous. :( Thanks

Comment: Greetings from 5 years in the future. Inconspicuous is right and us future people haven't improved it, it seems.  Microsoft should clearly mention this in the documentation for EmailAddressAttribute (and PhoneAttribute, etc) but I kinda pieced together the template information by looking at the documentation for the inherited DataTypeAttribute.  The documentation has no mention of the actual template name, though.  I tried Email.cshtml before Googling it and finding this (I guess I should have assumed it was the name of the attribute)

Comment: Ok I take that back.  The naming convention is in no way reflected by the attribute name.  Dammit, PhoneAttribute uses PhoneNumber.cshtml template and EmailAddressAttribute uses EmailAddress.cshtml.  This information would be handy somewhere in the docs... ARGH